# Escape EL in JSP that represent JSON data

Tags: json, jsp, escaping, xss

The Spring controller sets:

```
model.addAttribute("myJsonObj", JsonUtils.toJson(myObject));
```

The JSP has something like:

```
<script>
  var myObj = ${myJsonObj};
  (...)
```

How to properly protect this from any XSS exploit?

would break the JSON (double quotes, etc.)

What's the right strategy to avoid directly EL in the JSP?

Answer (score 1):

When JSP output `var myObj = ${myJsonObj};`, the behavior is the same as **eval** the script and cause XSS issue.
The solution is output `${myJsonObj}` as string, so malicious script will not execute. 
Then use `JSON.parse()` restore the string to javascript object, so you don't have to change other scripts.

You have to handle the double/single quote char when output `${myJsonObj}` as string.
This can be done using a JSP custom tag/EL function, for example:

```
var myObj = JSON.parse('<my:escapeEcmaScript value="${myJsonObj}"/>');
```

Or do it in Spring controller

```
model.addAttribute("myJsonObj", StringEscapeUtils.escapeEcmaScript(JsonUtils.toJson(myObject)));
//In JSP
//var myObj = JSON.parse('${myJsonObj}');
```

Comment: You meant to write <can't>?

Comment: I modify the answer and add more explanation.

Comment: I spent the last three hours trying to figure why my valid JSON string (in the Spring Controller) translated to an invalid JSON string after assigning it to a javascript variable in the JSP. After some troubleshooting and lots of researching I was sure I had to escape the invalid symbols, but could not find the proper way, thanks for pointing out!