# SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input with regards to Gson String variable passed from controller

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, model-view-controller, onchange

I'm currently working on an MVC framework project in which I am attempting to pass a stringfied JSON object using Gson from Java to a JSP file.

What I'm confused about is that I am able to alert the string in one situations but, in the other, I get the 'Syntax Error: Unexpected End of Input.'

Here is a code sample of what will "work". This code is just in the body of the HTML file.

```
<script type="text/javascript">alert('${var}');</script>
```

Here is an example of what will not work and trigger the error:

```
<select onchange="alert('${var}')"> . . . </select>
```

And also:

```
<select onchange="alert(${var})"> . . . </select>
```

My Gson String is an encoded version of a HashMap. I can't disclose too much information about the code due to an NDA.

Comment: json has double quotes, which works fine in script tag but not in onchange attribute which is also wrapped in double quotes. You need to escape the json's double quotes.

Comment: Would I need to do this within the Gson command?

Comment: See SO question [StringEscapeUtils.escapeEcmaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35664551/escape-el-in-jsp-that-represent-json-data)